# How to show th:value in Thymeleaf date format?

Tags: html, datepicker, thymeleaf

I have a problem with Thymeleaf date format when I send a date. The HTML shows the date correctly within a h3 tag but not inside the code of the datepicker and I can not understand why....

```html
<div> 
<label for="birthdate" th:text="#{editprofile.about4.birthdate}">Birth date</label> 
<label class="input"> 
<i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i> 
<input type="date" name="date" id="birthdate" class="form-control margin-bottom-20" th:value="${#dates.format(profile2about2th.birthdate,'yyyy/MM/dd')}" th:field="*{birthdate}"> 
</input> 
</label> 
<h3 th:text="${#dates.format(profile2about2th.birthdate,'yyyy/MM/dd')}"></h3> 
</div>
```

why it shows the date with hours in one place and correctly in the other...... input type="date" name="birthdate" id="birthdate" class="form-control margin-bottom-20" value=**"1932-10-10 00:00:00.0"**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`th:field` and `th:value` shouldn't be used on the same tag.  (`th:field` sets the `name`, `id` and `value` attributes of the tag it is on.)  You'll see that you would get the correct formatting if you left off `th:field`, but then the form wouldn't submit correctly.  In my opinion, the way to fix this is to:

Add an InitBinder method to your controller, like this:

```
@Controller
public class WhateverController {
    .
    .
    .

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder (WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"), true));
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Remove the th:value.  Your HTML should look like this:

```
<div> 
    <label for="birthdate" th:text="#{editprofile.about4.birthdate}">Birth date</label> 
    <label class="input"> 
        <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i> 
        <input type="date" name="date" id="birthdate" class="form-control margin-bottom-20" th:field="*{birthdate}" />
    </label> 

    <h3 th:text="${#dates.format(profile2about2th.birthdate,'yyyy/MM/dd')}"></h3> 
</div>
```

There are ways to add global binders as well, if you want this to work for your entire application and not just that one controller.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot Metroids. Is there a solution for pure Thymeleaf? I mean without doing it in the controller? (That's why i asked at the forum also).

Comment: If you want to use `th:field="*{birthdate}"` (and have it convert the POSTed value back to a java Date), you have to do it in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the date passed in as value (in this case **birthdate**) is of this format:

```
   yyyy-mm-dd
```

and **NOT** in the date picker's format mm/dd/yyyy

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value).